# When use a database?

Tags: database, mongodb, image, web, storage

I'm making a web-site for learning-purpose and in this site I'm planning to add some pictures.

My (maybe stupid) question is, when should you use a database for pictures? Like, is there at a specific amount of pictures that calls for a db, or are db's only for storing other types of information? Maybe db's should be used as soon as you don't want to store everything on your computer?

I was linked another page for a similar post below (my post would be a duplicate). That post is from 2008 and is mostly about SQL. Are there any new thoughts on the subject today, and is there any preferred database for storing different types of data?

Thank you

Comment: what kind of website you are making ?

Comment: A rather simple shop. I'm planning of having a few thumbnails with items the user can click for more information about that specific product. So far I've just done the landing page done with html and scc.

Comment: Well, have to say.... both? The topic is surely the same, and the link contains a lot of interesting information. It is 11 years old tho, and things may have changed. Maybe time for an update on the subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can divide website into 2 types :

1. Static website
2. Dynamic website

**Static Website :**

- which is created using Html , Css , Javascript , Jquery
- normally have less number of pages (5 to 10)
- it is just used to display information written in HTML page

Example : Simple Website with common pages like homepage,aboutus,contactus, and 2 - 3 pages with simple information

**Dynamic Website :**

- generally no limit of pages
- used to load data/information dynamically
- which is build using **frontend** plus **backend** and **database**

**database** : database is used to store values into appropriate table/document

> example of databases :
>   MySQL,Sqlite,Oracle,SQL,PostgressSQL,MongoDB,Redis etc..

**backend** : it is server side code written to perform  `CREATE, READ, UPDATE, DELETE` called as **CRUD** operations into Database  and other operations using different programming langauges

> backend done with programming Languages :
>   PHP,Java,NodeJS,Python,Go,Ruby ...etc

**frontend** : it is used to make http request to backend function and display data on page as per data provided by backend

> here frontend can be using  HTML,CSS,Javascript,Jquery,Ajax  or  modern
>   frontend technologies like : AngulerJS , ReactJS , VueJS

Example : Blog Website, Ecommerce Website, and many more ....

Comment: Thank you very much for the very nice explanation Saurabh. I translate this as, as long as you don't really have to load data/information dynamically, there is no need for a database. It would be different if I made a big page with plenty of products where pictures, prices, and inventory might change continuously.